# BUilding Flex project with unit testing on cruise control

Tags: apache-flex, unit-testing, builder, cruisecontrol

I have a flex application build with actionscript 3 on flex builder  with unit testing on it using flexUnit4. I want to build this project on my cruise control and i don't know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys for the help,

Finally i managed to run flex on CI which generate my test results in html file. What i actually have to do is create a build.xml file which can run with ant. Build file has path to all the libraries of flex unit installed on pc or CC unit and the path to main file in your application. To build our project on Cruise Control you just need to edit the build.bat file on your CC.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have AIR installed so it can write directly to the file system, although there are [other ways](http://techpolesen.blogspot.com/2007/10/flex-trace-and-logging.html).  From there, your buildbot can examine the output programmatically and pass or fail as desired.  See the description on the [Digital Dump Truck blog post](http://digitaldumptruck.jotabout.com/?p=26) for one such method.

Answer (score 0):

Would this blog post be useful?

http://www.aaronspjut.com/mind/index.php/2009/05/23/continuous-integration-with-flex-3-cruisecontrolrb-and-flexunit4/

Sorry for the lack of information from me, I am not familiar with cruise-control.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the link but i already tried that but problem with this approach is it is using adobe air for generating results. which i cannot used as my application is not desktop. But i was able to clear my problem with the help of my proffesor.